# lightSlider plugin not working on first time load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I make the slider on my website using lightSlider,below html code i am using (note that i am using asp.net mvc) and i am using loop in load images

```
             <ul id="imageGallery">
                @foreach (var i in Model.Images)
                {
                    <li data-thumb="@i" data-src="@i">
                        <img src="@i" />
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
```

and here is code jquery to load my slider

```
 $(document).ready(function () {  
         $('#imageGallery').lightSlider({
             gallery: true,
             item: 1,
             thumbItem: 9,
              slideMargin: 0,
              speed: 500,
              auto: true,
              loop: true,
              onSliderLoad: function () {
               $('#imageGallery').removeClass('cS-hidden');
              }
        });
  });
```

So my problem is slider displaying not correctly in the first time
Please see my slider is loaded here [slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M4lZ.png)

But when i **reload** the page it is working correctly.

I am not sure what am i missing here?